# Commander damage from Mimic Vat token?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-commander-damage

I've exiled my commander using [Mimic Vat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mimic%20Vat). Do the tokens it creates from it deal commander damage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. The Commander rules state ([CR903.3](http://www.yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/#R9033)) state: "[Being a commander] is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute **of the card itself**. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones." and drives the point home with the last example: "A permanent that's copying a commander (such as a Body Double, for example, copying a commander in a player's graveyard) is not a commander."

Answer (score 7):

No, it is an at attribute of the card itself, not a characteristic that is copyable. From the [Mtg Comprehensive Rules](http://www.wizards.com/magic/comprules/MagicCompRules_20120601.pdf):

> 903.3. Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.
>
> **Example:** A commander that's been turned face down (due to Ixidron's effect, for example) is still a commander. A commander that's copying another card (due to Cytoshape's effect, for example) is still a commander. A permanent that's copying a commander (such as a Body Double, for example, copying a commander in a player's graveyard) is not a commander.

A cards characteristics are:

> 109.3. An object's characteristics are name, mana cost, color, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, expansion symbol, rules text, abilities, power, toughness, loyalty, hand modifier, and life modifier. Objects can have some or all of these characteristics. **Any other information about an object isn't a characteristic**. For example, characteristics don't include whether a permanent is tapped, a spell's target, an object's owner or controller, what an Aura enchants, and so on.